# Difference between DB::table('table') and model::('table')

Tags: database, laravel, orm, relational-database

on laravel we can access by using `DB::table('table')->get();` or using `model::('table')->all();`
My question is what's the difference between them ?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this because `Model` and the `DB` facade both implement functions that yield a `Builder` instance.

https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html
https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

The difference is, instances of `Model` have properties which set up a `Builder` with predesignated information, *like* table, and also provide it with events, relationship information, specific static bindings, and a bunch of other handy helpers that constrain to objects and make **object-oriented programming** easier.

So yes, you can use a model and then take the query `Builder` object and change its table (just like you can change anything else about a `Builder`), but it's fighting a system specifically designed to make query building easier.

At heart, what Laravel does is take the Symfony2 framework and streamline it so everything is simpler. Models are one such instance of this.