# Laravel accessors using Query Builder

Tags: php, laravel, accessor

Trying to get Accessors in query builder but throwing error "**`Undefined property: stdClass::$shorcontent`** "

```
//controller
        public function index(){
        $articles = DB::table('articles')->paginate(10);
        return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles], compact('articles'));
    }
```

Here is the Model file with Accessors

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'content', 'live', 'post_on'
    ];

    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function getShortContentAttribute()
    {

        return substr($this->content,0, random_int(60, 150));
    }
}
```

Here is the View

```
//article/index.blade.php View
<td class="col-md-6">{{ $article->shortcontent }} </td>
```

**The same code working when i use eloquent instead of query builder, like this**

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = Article::paginate(10);
    return view('articles.index', ['articles' => $articles], compact('articles'));
}
```

Comment: Try `shortContent`. You're definitely missing the t in the name.

Comment: @aynber throwing error "Undefined property: stdClass::$shortContent"

Comment: Tried `$article->short_content` ?

Comment: @linktoahref tried short_Content and short_content both, again same error

Comment: Does your model has `short_content` field ?

Comment: @linktoahref 

public function getshort_ContentAttribute()
    {
     return substr($this->content,0, random_int(60, 150));
    }

like this ?

Comment: `short_content` column/field in the table, which your model is associated with

Comment: please post your model fields

Comment: @Exprator check answer's description again

Comment: so you are trying to make the content small right?

Comment: @Exprator, yes i do previously i am using  {{ substr($article->content,0, random_int(60, 150)) }} previously directly in the views and working fine but i want to make my code organised with assessor

Comment: change the accessor name to getContentAttribute(), and do remember model attribute can only access it, thus the second one works not the first one as mentioned by you

Comment: no, getContentAttribute not changing anything

Comment: Why are you passing `$articles` twice in your controller method? Once is enough.

Comment: @Fahmi, this is out if the issue.

Answer (score 11):

This answer is late and you might have found your solution, but hope it helps someone else.

Short answer, the DB facade doesn't have access to accessors and mutators defined in the model. Only objects made by instances of the model can have access to accessors and mutators.

I believe the issue here is that using the DB facade only creates the Query Builder without any reference to accessors or mutators you have set in the Article Model. DB facade only queries the database using the query builder and returns an object independent from the Article Model.

However, the Model facade will build a query builder but the instance of the object created will have access to accessors and mutators as it is an object instance of the Article Model class.

Check out this SO answer:
[Difference between DB and Model facade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37095032/5393142)

Accessors are only accessed once you attempt to retrieve the value of the  attribute from the model instance, for example:

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$shortContent = $article->short_content;
```

This is explained further [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Thus if you wish to access accessors, then you would have to use the Model facade i.e. `Article::paginate(10)`.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing to append short_content attribute. Just add this

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{

protected $fillable = [
    'user_id', 'content', 'live', 'post_on'
];
protected $appends = ['short_content'];
protected $guarded = ['id'];

public function getShortContentAttribute()
{

return substr($this->content,0, random_int(60, 150));

}

}
```